# Saber mi ip privada desde python

Tags: python, ip

estoy creando un pequeño chat que va a funcionar en una red local, les explico la situación:
en donde estudio hay 3 salas con computadoras y están bloqueadas páginas como facebook, twitter y otras redes sociales, por lo que pensé que sería buena idea crear un chat para el resto de estudiantes (para ganar un poco de dinero), para esto pensé en poner servidores en 2 o 3 computadoras (por si es que alguna está apagada), me da pereza ir a poner `ipconfig` y editar el `sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5000))` (lo de 127.0.0.1 es solo por poner una ip) en cada una de las computadoras, ademas de que trasteando un poco me he dado cuenta de que reinician el router (porque cuando pongo `ipconfig` por alguna u otra razón en la misma computadora en un día distinto me doy cuenta de que la ip cambia), por lo que me preguntaba si es que ¿hay alguna función de alguna librería o algo que retorne la ip privada de la maquina que se está usando?

Comment: mira lo siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib

Comment: Si es solo para el bind, basta que uses la ip `0.0.0.0`, que representa las IPs de todas las interfaces de red que tenga la máquina.

Comment: Hola, la Ip cambia por que son dinamicas, y así esta configurado el router, el orden se asigna como vayan conectandose, ahora si claro que si puedes usar un comando, yo usuaria los comandos **ipconfig** (Windows), ejecutandose desde ´python´, y con una **expresión regular** recuperar la IP  asiganada si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: te sugiero que configures tu ip para que sea estatica, claro con la ip, mascara de subred y puerta de enlace predeterminada, con la que se encuentra activa.
Espero te sirva.
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de [encontrar la dirección IP de tu computadora en python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib). Una opción es hacer una conexión al DNS de Google (disponible en Internet en la dirección 8.8.8.8) y revisar la dirección usada como fuente de la comunicación. Usando esta opción, puedes detectar la dirección IP que tiene salida a Internet.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

Comment: El pidió IP privada, el metodo que planteas devuelve la IP pública

Answer (score -1):

buscando encontré un código que podría servirte. es muy sencillo, creo que una explicación esta de mas pero nada que en las wikis no encuentras. espero te sirva

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee tambien [answer]  para aprender a realizar una buena respuesta. Que aporta esta respuesta a la que ya fue aceptada en su momento?